How to ensure image fits within a container without overlapping the input field, regardless of its size
Description
Currently, if the user captures an image and pastes it, the image in the img-preview-container overlaps the userInput. This behavior can be explicitly observed when the user captures and pastes an image that has a longer height than its width to the chatbot.
Expected Behavior
Make the image shown inside the img-preview-container by clipping the image content at the border of the container element, regardless of the size of the image that the user pasted with using the 'ctrl' and 'v' keys.
Current Behavior
Currently, if the user utilizes the PrtSc key to capture the specific part of the screen and paste it in the text input field with ctrl+v, the pasted image overlaps the text input field.



const promptInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
const chatContainer = document.getElementById("chatContainer");
const typingIndicator = document.getElementById("typingIndicator");
const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
const sidebarContent = document.getElementById("sidebarContent");
const imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");

async function sendMessage() {
  const prompt = promptInput.value.trim();
  if (!prompt && imageContainer.children.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter a message or add an image.");  // Browser pop up message
    return;
  }

  // Collect image data
  const images = Array.from(imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.img-preview'))
    .map(img => img.src.split(',')[1]); // Extract base64 data

  addMessage(prompt, 'user', images);
  promptInput.value = "";

  showTypingIndicator();

  const generatedText = await generateText(prompt, images);
  addMessage(generatedText, 'bot');

  hideTypingIndicator();
  //clearImagePreviews(); Add this code if you want the image in the imageContainer disappear if the user sends the image.
}

async function generateText(prompt, images) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/generate_text_stream", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ prompt, images }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error("Error:", response.statusText);
      return "Error occurred while generating response.";
    }

    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let isFinished = false;
    let generatedTextContent = "";

    while (!isFinished) {
      const { done, value } = await reader.read();
      if (done) {
        isFinished = true;
        break;
      }
      generatedTextContent += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
    }

    return generatedTextContent;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return "An error occurred.";
  }
}

function addMessage(text, type, images = []) {
  const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
  messageDiv.className = `message ${type}`;

  const messageContent = document.createElement("div");
  messageContent.className = "message-bubble fadeIn";
  messageContent.innerHTML = `<p>${text}</p>`;

  images.forEach(src => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `data:image/png;base64,${src}`;
    img.classList.add("message-image");
    messageContent.appendChild(img);
  });

  messageDiv.appendChild(messageContent);
  chatContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
  chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
}

function clearImagePreviews() {
  while (imageContainer.firstChild) {
    imageContainer.removeChild(imageContainer.firstChild);
  }
  checkImageContainerVisibility();
}

let typingTimeout;

function showTypingIndicator() {
  clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
  typingIndicator.style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideTypingIndicator() {
  typingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    typingIndicator.style.display = "none";
  }, 1000);
}

function handleKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    sendMessage();
  }
}

function toggleSidebar() {
  if (sidebar.style.width === "500px") {
    sidebar.style.width = "0";
    sidebarContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    sidebar.style.width = "500px";
    sidebarContent.style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onload = () => addMessage("Hello! How can I assist you today?", 'bot');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('userInput');

  textInput.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    const items = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).items;
    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
        const file = item.getAsFile();
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
          displayImage(event.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });

  function displayImage(src) {
    const imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
    imgContainer.classList.add('img-preview-container');

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.classList.add('img-preview');

    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.classList.add('remove-button');
    removeButton.textContent = '✖';
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      imgContainer.remove();
      checkImageContainerVisibility();
    });

    imgContainer.appendChild(img);
    imgContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
    imageContainer.appendChild(imgContainer);
    checkImageContainerVisibility();

    const all_images = imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.img-preview-container');
    all_images.forEach(img => img.style.width = `${100 / all_images.length - 10}%`);
  }

  function checkImageContainerVisibility() {
    if (imageContainer.children.length > 0) {
      imageContainer.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      imageContainer.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }

  // Initial check to hide image container if empty
  checkImageContainerVisibility();
});
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f0f2f5;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

/* Generate report button styling */
button, input[type="submit"] {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

/* Form styling */
form {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}

select, input[type="submit"] {
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
}

select {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Report page styling */
.report-container {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow: auto;
}

a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Section that will show report content */
.report-content {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.report-content iframe {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    height: 600px;
}



/* Chat Bot */
.container {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.chat {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}

.message {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.message.user {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.message-bubble {
    padding: 12px 18px;
    max-width: 70%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
}

.message.user .message-bubble {
    background-color: #3182ce;
    color: white;
}

.message.bot .message-bubble {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    color: #333;
}


.message-image {
    max-width: 100px; /* Set the maximum width for the image */
    max-height: 100px; /* Set the maximum height for the image */
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: cover; /* Ensures the image retains its aspect ratio */
}


input[type="text"] {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
}

.send-button {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #3182ce;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.send-button:hover {
    background-color: #2c5282;
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #666;
    position: static;
    border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fadeIn {
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 10px auto 0;
    }

    .chat {
        height: 300px;
    }

    .input-container {
        max-width: 95%;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    .send-button {
        padding: 10px 14px;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .footer {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}

.typing-indicator {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 4px;
    animation: typing 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0%,
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
}

/* Side bar */
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: white;
}

.sidebar-content {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar-content h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-content p {
    padding: 10px;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #3182ce;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-button:hover {
    background-color: #2c5282;
}

img {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.image-container {
    width: 100%;
    /*padding: 12px 18px;*/


    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*border: 1px solid #444;*/
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.img-preview-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 15%;
}

.img-preview {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.remove-button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.remove-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Portfolio Backtesting</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Portfolio Backtesting</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/">
      <label for="cs_model">Choose Cross-Sectional Model:</label>
      <select id="cs_model" name="cs_model">
        <option value="EW">Equal Weight (EW)</option>
        <option value="MSR">Maximum Sharpe Ratio (MSR)</option>
        <option value="GMV">Global Minimum Variance (GMV)</option>
        <option value="MDP">Minimum Drawdown Risk (MDP)</option>
        <option value="EMV">Equal Risk Contribution (EMV)</option>
        <option value="RP">Risk Parity (RP)</option>
      </select>

      <label for="ts_model">Choose Time-Series Model:</label>
      <select id="ts_model" name="ts_model">
        <option value="VT">Volatility Targeting (VT)</option>
        <option value="CVT">Conditional Value at Risk Targeting (CVT)</option>
        <option value="KL">Kelly Criterion (KL)</option>
        <option value="CPPI">
          Constant Proportion Portfolio Insurance (CPPI)
        </option>
      </select>

      <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" />
    </form>

    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <button class="toggle-button" onclick="toggleSidebar()">☰</button>
      <div class="sidebar-content" id="sidebarContent">
        <div class="container bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
          <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-4 text-center">ChatBot</h1>
          <div class="chat" id="chatContainer"></div>
          <div class="image-container hidden" id="imageContainer"></div>
          <div class="flex">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="userInput"
              placeholder="Type your message here..."
              class="outline-none"
              onkeyup="handleKeyPress(event)"
            />
            <button class="send-button" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
          </div>
          <div class="typing-indicator" id="typingIndicator"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>




"Make the image shown inside the img-preview-container"... It is not clear how you want this to happen: clipping the image content at the border of the container element, or shrinking the whole picture until it fits the container? This is all about proportionality. If you want to shrink it, you might finish with a skiny little vertical thing, if its width is significantly shorter than its height. Is this what you want?

Clipping the image content at the border of the container element is what I was thinking of. I've edited the post for a clearer purpose.

Try adding CSS object-fit: cover  or fill to the <img>.

I've tried adding both CSS object-fit attributes but none of those solved the problem.

The easier way of doing this is adding a CSS rule:
.image-container {
    overflow:hidden
}

This way, anything extra will be hidden.

Doesn't this make the image disappear if the image overlaps? I was intending to show the portion of the image by clipping the image content if it overlaps.

@loupdaniel What exactly do you mean with overlap? I understand you have a container, and want to maintain the image within the original boundaries of the container. Actually, the part of the image that does not fit inside, the "extra content", is what "overflows" from the container. That's exactly what the overflow CSS property is designed to control. When you say that .image-container should overflow:hidden, it shows the image all the way up to the boundary of the container, but nothing beyond that. I tested it in the snippet you gave, and it worked as intended.

I've misunderstood your solution that it would literally make the image disappear if it overflows. Tested the code and works great!
